# "If I where you I ^would do^ the same" Vs. "If I where you I ^would have done^ the same"

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I called my friend and he answered the call and then ask me: "Is it emergency? because if not now I'm in a very important meeting. If it is not emergency, I'll call you immediately later."  Later he called me and he was sorry about that. I told him  "If I were you I **would do** the same".

Now, someone noted me to say "If I were you I **would have done** the same". My question if is it correct and if it is not what is the difference between

> "If I were you, I **would do** the same.
>
> "If I were you, I would **have done** the same"

and why it is correct to use one form and no the other form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation you have described *"If I were you, I would have done the same"* is correct. It is called the mixed conditional sentence. *If I were you* refers to the present and it is unreal. *I would have done the same* is unreal too but it refers to the past. Your friend told you that he would call you back in the past, that's why you need to use the pattern *would + have + past participle*. Here are more examples like this:

1. *If I were you, I wouldn't have made such a mistake.* (the mistake was made in the past and in the second part of the sentence I refer to the past)
2. If I were you, I would have quit such a lousy job a long time ago. (in other words, you had to do it a long time ago; again, we refer to the past)

*If I were you, I would do the same* is a conditional sentence of the second type. It means both parts of the sentence refer to the present. That is, if I were you **now**, I would act in the same way **now**.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put the structure of the Second Conditional for you. " **Sub+ be verb (mostly were+..., + Sub+ would/should/could/might+ v1(a present form of the verb)+ Ext.....** As you see this structure follows the present form of the situation. If you put "Have" in a sentence it goes straight to past. This is also not wrong but the scenario you wrote should be in present form.